# How to have python code and markdown in one cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Can jupyter notebook support inline python code (arthritic calculations, or plot a figure) in markdown cell, or verse visa. Have both python code and markdown in one cell.

Comment: Maybe provide some context/example, I can't figure out why one would need something like this. You can always create a new cell and you can include images/latex/etc. in your markdown cell.

Comment: For instance, have an inline calculation, `a = b + c`, instead of showing the equation, I would like to get the number directly.

Comment: If you can forego formatting, you can always use `print()` in a code cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible but there is an extension that you could use: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/python-markdown

That way you can display the result (and only the result) of a python statement inside a markdown cell.

Answer (score 24):

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown("# Hello World!"))
```

Comment: `import from IPython.display import display` and `display(Markdown("# Hello World!"))` is better.

Comment: @fx-krin your import statement appears to be invalid, it was close though

Comment: `from IPython.display import display`
`display(Markdown("# Hello World!"))`

Comment: @fx-kirin Thanks. I just tried your code and it works. May I know why putting adding that "display" function before "Markdown" is better?

Comment: @jasonleonhard It was just typo. Sorry.

Comment: @kevin-zhu Without display, you need to put the Markdown code in the last line of your cell.

Comment: @fx-kirin Thanks, I've updated the code in the asnwer.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept Colab as 'jupyter notebook' , then the answer is YES.

Here some examples.

- Upper part, code cell
- Lower part, markdown cell

[image]

Code in the code cell:

```
#@markdown  # Title

#@markdown   **black**

#@markdown  `code stuff`

#@markdown ![Image in a code cell]( https://i.imgur.com/6Z1i8zF.png)
```

Very useful for when you want to insert an image within a code cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic function below

```py
%%md_with_code
"""
# Title

More markdown
"""

my_code.execute()
```

Here is the code for the magic function

```py
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython import get_ipython
import ast

@register_cell_magic
def md_with_code(line, cell):
    parsed = ast.parse(cell)
    if not parsed:
        return
    
    if isinstance(parsed.body[0], ast.Expr) and isinstance(parsed.body[0].value, ast.Str):
        display(Markdown(parsed.body[0].value.s.strip()))
    get_ipython().run_cell(cell)

del md_with_code


del md_with_code
```