# How to adopt markdown feature in a long function in jupyter notebook? (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Jupyter notebook is attractive to me for its code cell design and markdown support.
It make code more readable for me.
However, when I write a python funciton, I have to put all function code in one cell. Otherwise it cause error. That means that I can not use markdown feature in one funciton. That is so disappointing to me.
Is there any good way？

Comment: You cannot expect to execute a part of the function and expect it to work as intended (ex few first lines). A cell is the smallest partition. If you need to make a comment to the code use python comment syntax. Try `""" coment """` for multiline comments. Use markdown between code cells.

Answer (score 1):

That however is not possible but there is an extension that you could use: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/python-markdown
That way you can display the result (and only the result) of a python statement inside a markdown cell.

You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353368/how-to-have-python-code-and-markdown-in-one-cell) below for additional information and cheat sheet on all markdowns can be referred from the [doc](https://ingeh.medium.com/markdown-for-jupyter-notebooks-cheatsheet-386c05aeebed).